# Stop next event listener from firing when one type of event is handled

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, selectors-api, event-delegation

I have 2 click listeners set up, these handle showing a modal and removing a note. These listeners use event delegation and is set up on parent container. The Note is rendered afters when users inputs one.
The issue is, when user clicks on a note , a modal pops up to show its content but at the same time the remove note listener is also fired.
How do I stop next listener from firing when one is handled.

```
/*Controller.js*/

async function removeNote(ele) {
  let noteId = { id: ele.dataset.id };
  let deletedNote = await sendAPIRequest("deleteNote", "DELETE", noteId);
  let localDeletedNote = deleteNoteFromLocal(deletedNote);
  NoteView.removeNotefromView(localDeletedNote);
}

function closeModal(ele) {
  let modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

  if (!document.querySelector("body").contains(ele)) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function showModal(ele) {
  let noteId = { id: ele.dataset.id };
  Modal.addDisplayModalHandler();
}

function init() {

  /* NoteView.detectNoteChange(updateNoteDetails); */
  NoteView.addHandlerShowModalOnClick(showModal);
  NoteView.addHandlerRemoveCard(removeNote);
  /* Modal.addDisplayModalHandler(displayModal); */
  Modal.addHandlerCloseModal(closeModal);
}

init();
```

/*Task.js*/

```
import { callCorrectFunc } from "../helper.js";
import { Note as noteData } from "../model.js";

class NoteView {
  _parentElement = document.querySelector(".task_card_container");

  /* constructor(title, body, date, priority) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
    this.date = date;
    this.priority = priority;
  } */

  addHandlerRemoveCard(handler) {
    document.querySelector(".notes_list").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let ele = e.target.closest(".task_card") || null;
      if (ele !== null) {
        let action = getDataAttr(ele);
        if (action === "open_modal") {
          handler(ele);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /*   addHandler(handler){
    document.querySelector('.task_card_container').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
      callCorrectFunc(e);
    })
  } */


  addHandlerShowModalOnClick(handler) {
    document.querySelector(".notes_list").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
     
      let ele = e.target.closest(".task_card") || null;
      if (ele !== null) {
        let action = getDataAttr(ele);
        if (action === "open_modal") {
          handler(ele);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  detectNoteChange(handler) {
    document
      .querySelector(".task_card_container")
      .addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
        console.log(e.target);
        let ele = e.target.closest("div");
        if (!ele) return;
        handler(ele);
      });
  }

  renderUI() {
    let badgeColor =
      noteData.currentNote.priority === "1"
        ? "text-bg-danger"
        : noteData.currentNote.priority === "2"
        ? "text-bg-warning"
        : "text-bg-success";
    let template = this.#generateNoteTemplate(noteData.currentNote, badgeColor);
    this._parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", template);

    this.clearTaskModal();
  }


  removeNotefromView(note) {
    document.querySelector(`div[data-id="${note.objectId}"]`).remove();
  }

  #generateNoteTemplate({ id, title, body, priority, objectId }, badgeColor) {
    return `
        <div class="task_card" data-id=${objectId} data-action="open_modal">
                <div class="task_card_header">
                  <p id="task_card_header_text" contenteditable="true" >${title}</p>
                  <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="delete_card_button" data-id=${objectId} data-action="close" role="button">disabled_by_default</span>
                </div>
                <div class="task_card_body">
                  <div class="task_card_body_content" contenteditable="true">
                  ${body}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card_metadata">
                  <p class="card_metadata_body ${badgeColor}">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                      priority_high
                    </span> 
                    <span class="card_metadata_priority">${
                      priority === "1"
                        ? "High"
                        : priority === "2"
                        ? "Medium"
                        : "Low"
                    }</span>
                  </p>
                  <p class="card_metadata_body text-bg-secondary">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                      schedule
                      </span>
                    <span class="card_metadata_date"> ${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}</span>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>`;
  }

  clearTaskModal() {
    task_title.value = "";
    task_body.value = "";
    task_priority.value = "3";
  }
}

export default new NoteView();
```

Index.HTML

```
   <div class="task_card_container">
              <div class="notes_list">

              </div>
          </div>
```

[image: UI]

Comment: No, thanks for the help, i've managed to come up with an solution based on the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the event to your handlers

```
handler(ele,e);
```

and use stopPropagation

```
async function removeNote(ele, e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // ... rest of your code
}

function showModal(ele, e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  // ... rest of your code
}
```

I personally prefer one event handler on the closest static container so something like this, then you do not need to pass the event and do stop propagastion in the function

```
addHandlerNoteActions(showModalHandler, removeNoteHandler) {
  this._parentElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const ele = e.target.closest(".task_card");
    if (!ele) return;

    const action = ele.dataset.action;

    switch (action) {
      case "open_modal":
        e.stopPropagation();
        showModalHandler(ele);
        break;
      case "close":
        e.stopPropagation();
        removeNoteHandler(ele);
        break;
      // ... other cases ...
    }
  });
}
```

Lastly I do not see the need for async operations other than for the  removeNote

Comment: Okay, thanks will try out your solution

Answer (score 0):

You do mention [*event-delegation*](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), but it seems that both functions `addHandlerShowModalOnClick` and `addHandlerRemoveCard` do event-delegation not entirely correct. At least `addHandlerRemoveCard` needs to be implemented in a way that it identifies the click-target as a remove-button and not alike `addHandlerShowModalOnClick` where one generically targets ...

```
e.target.closest(".task_card");
```

For `addHandlerRemoveCard` it rather should be something like ...

```
e.target.closest(".remove_button");
```

Identifying the remove-button click correctly is crucial for `addHandlerRemoveCard` and every other action that is going to follow.

E.g. something like that ...

```
addHandlerRemoveCard(handler) {
  document
    .querySelector(".notes_list")
    .addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {

      // - targeting a remove-button first, assuring
      //   that the note actually has to be removed.
      //
      // let ele = evt.target.closest(".task_card") || null;

      const  elmRemove = target.closest(".remove_button");
      const  elmCard = elmRemove && target.closest(".task_card");

      if (elmCard !== null) {
        handler(elmCard);
      }
    });
}

async function removeNote(ele) {
  let noteId = { id: ele.dataset.id };
  let deletedNote = await sendAPIRequest("deleteNote", "DELETE", noteId);
  let localDeletedNote = deleteNoteFromLocal(deletedNote);
  NoteView.removeNotefromView(localDeletedNote);
}

NoteView.addHandlerRemoveCard(removeNote);
```